# Call A Function When All Button Clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to call a function when the button clicked. It will check the SQL Injection for page controls.

It needs to be default function for button control. How is this possible ?

Example

```
public void Button1_Click()
{
// Calling Default Function For Button After Run Logic Code
// Logic Code Here
}
```

The default function calling before all logic codes in button.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  If you just want to call a method from your click handler, what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: It will be default for button control. I will write to code for once and whem the buttons in project clicked, the function calling automatically. Is it clear for you now ?

Comment: Sounds like you either want to (1) put a method call at the start of all of your buttons, or (2) write a custom `Button` object which inherets from the standard `Button` and performs its default action on any click event, then invokes other attached click handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want every instance of a control throughout the code to perform custom logic, and only want to define that logic once, then it sounds like you're talking about building a [custom control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx).

For example, you can build a control that inherits from `Button`.  It's been a *very* long time since I've had to deal with WebForms, but the general principle in object oriented programming is the same.  The overall structure *might* be as simple as something like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        // perform your custom logic here
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

(But the framework may require some more ceremony in the form of attributes, other methods to override, etc.  This is just a starting point for your development, introducing you to the broad concept.  It's worth looking into other examples of custom controls anyway just to see how you can further customize and polish your control.)

The idea with this is such that throughout your codebase you would use this custom button isntead of the standard button.  Since this inherits the `Button` class, it is a `Button` and can do everything a `Button` can do.  But it also does whatever code you add to this class.

So you just write the logic in one object, then use that object throughout your code.  Your `web.config` would need to globally register a "tag prefix" to allow you to reference the control in your pages:

```
<system.web>    
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="myControls" Assembly="MyControlsAssembly" namespace="MyNamespace">
      </add>
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

(Use values that apply to your scenario of course, your own assembly name and a more meaningful tab prefix for example.)

And you'd use that control in your pages:

```
<myControls:MyButton runat="server"></myControls:MyButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you do this?

```
//Create Function
private void Function()
{
    //Do something
}

protected void Button1_Click()
{        
    // Logic Code Here

    //Call function
    Function();
}

protected void Button2_Click()
{        
    // Logic Code Here

    //Call function
    Function();
}
```

Comment: All  of buttons in project ? NO.

Comment: What do you mean by *All of buttons in project* ? @ÖmürCanYurdugül

Comment: It will be a default function for all of buttons in project. For Example ;

<asp:Button deafultAction="true" /> Then it will automatically importing to button click event.

Comment: If all buttons have `OnClick="Button1_Click"` then all buttons will use this function. If not you'll have to call the function on all `OnClick` functions.

Comment: As @hmax said, you'll need to assign the same Click_Event to all buttons, then determine which button was clicked to do some job by switch, and in default, run your function.

Comment: @hmax All buttons doing different logic process guys. How is that possible when you set the same OnClick function to all buttons ?

Comment: @ÖmürCanYurdugül Then you'll need a different `OnClick` function for each button... You can still write code that you want to run on each click in `Function()`, you'll just have to call that function in each `OnClick` function.